# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for boolean android.os.SystemProperties.native_get_boolean(java.lang.String, boolean)

Tags: java, android, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm trying to resolve the official Android Tutorial, but when I do some modifications requested by tutorial to Android's Hello World project, I receive this error:

```
Launching application: com.example.antonio.myapplication3/com.example.antonio.myapplication3.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "com.example.antonio.myapplication3/com.example.antonio.myapplication3.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for boolean android.os.SystemProperties.native_get_boolean(java.lang.String, boolean) (tried Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get_1boolean and Java_android_os_SystemProperties_native_1get_1boolean__Ljava_lang_String_2Z)
at android.os.SystemProperties.native_get_boolean(Native Method)
at android.os.SystemProperties.getBoolean(SystemProperties.java:116)
at android.text.TextUtils.<clinit>(TextUtils.java:1888)
at android.os.Environment$UserEnvironment.<init>(Environment.java:151)
at android.os.Environment.initForCurrentUser(Environment.java:126)
at android.os.Environment.<clinit>(Environment.java:120)
at android.os.Environment.getLegacyExternalStorageDirectory(Environment.java:413)
at android.os.Debug.<clinit>(Debug.java:98)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleHELO(DdmHandleHello.java:146)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:90)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleFEAT(DdmHandleHello.java:158)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleHello.handleChunk(DdmHandleHello.java:92)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: android.os.Debug
at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleMPRQ(DdmHandleProfiling.java:189)
at android.ddm.DdmHandleProfiling.handleChunk(DdmHandleProfiling.java:88)
at org.apache.harmony.dalvik.ddmc.DdmServer.dispatch(DdmServer.java:171)
Aborted
```

To note that this error only occur when I run the app in my real phone. If I try run it on AVD everything run well.

I created a simple blank project in AndroidStudio and I did the following modifications...

The only modifications that I've made in project were:

- Create "colors.xml" in values directory

  ```
  <color name="myOrange">#ffff6e11</color>
  ```
- Create "themes.xml" in values directory

  ```
  <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
  <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
      parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
  </style>

  <!-- ActionBar styles -->
  <style name="MyActionBar"
      parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
      <item name="android:background">@color/myOrange</item>
  </style>
  ```
- Change theme in "android_manifest.xml"

  android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >

This modifications were made in a blank project created in Android Studio.

My phone is a BQ Aquaris E5 HD, and I'm using Android Studio.

I appreciate your attention.

Comment: Can you post also the code that gives you this problem?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this question?